# Regex to extract CSS classnames and IDs

Tags: c#, regex

I have some CSS and I'm looking to create a list of all the class names and identifiers. This is what I have:

```
var TheList = new List<string>();
var Test2 = Regex.Matches(TheCSS, ".-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*(?=[^}]*\\{)");

foreach(Match m in Test2)
{
    TheList.Add(m.Value);
}
```

The problem is that there are some unwanted elements:

```
body
:hover
select
input
label
[for
input
[type
'radio
```

I've tried with several regex expressions that I've found online; this one is the closest but it's not perfect yet. Basically, it needs to include only elements that begin with `#` and `.` so as to avoid `body` and `[type` and then not include pseudo-selectors like `:hover`

What do I need to change in the regex to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Prepare a sample on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ with your testcase.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: here you go: http://regexr.com?37uc4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following [the CSS standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#tokenization), a class or ID must match `[_A-Za-z0-9\-]+`. A class or ID thus matches that string prefixed directly by either a `#` or `.`.

After determining that all you need to do is ensure that it's followed by a `{` before an `}` occurs to make sure you're outside a rule.

The resulting regexp would then be: `([\.#][_A-Za-z0-9\-]+)[^}]*{`

[Your sample case](http://regexr.com?37uc7). Same regexp applied to [Facebook CSS](http://regexr.com?37ucd).

Comment: Ok, this looks great. I changed it to ([\\.#][_A-Za-z0-9\\-]+)[^}][*{] to make sure to include * as an ending possibility.

Comment: It doesn't work if a selector contains multiple classes or ids. It will match only the first id or class from a selector. So this way you cannot extract all of them.

Comment: Based on that a better solution would be to use a positive lookahead: `([\.#][_A-Za-z0-9\-]+)(?=[^}]+{)`